# why wont my net book recognize that its wireless

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu on my old net book. but it wont act as if it were wireless. only Ethernet. Do i need to install drivers to get the wireless hardware to work with Ubuntu operating system

Comment: `but it wont act as if it were wireless` I don't get what you want to say here. Please clarify your question and add more details about the version of Ubuntu and about what you have tried so far.

Comment: probably not, almost all pci drivers are included in the linux kernel. open a terminal and type the following commands `iwconfig` also, `lspci -v`.

Comment: @mchid that's not entirely true - some wireless adapters need proprietary drivers which aren't included because of licensing

Comment: @ThomasW. yes it is "probably" not entirely you are correct some aren't most are which is why the output of lspci -v would really help us out here

Comment: really, we don't need the whole output, only the paragraph for "Network controller:"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

System settings

Software & updates

Additional drivers

It will take a little time while it searches for drivers. In my case, I needed to install a proprietary Broadcom driver.